# Hidden Parameter where values are specified - Report preview telling me the parameter is missing value

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services

I'm new to this role and I feel like this should be fairily straightforward although I can't find the answer out there.

I'm tasked with creating a template to be used for a variety of reports.  I'm using Visual Studio 2013 to create templates for SSRS reports. Part of my task is to explore creating a parameter with user defined values that the report developer can select before publishing the report.

For example, one parameter I want to make is for the security level, so for simplicity, I have two values that I specified - Restricted and General Consumption.  I do not want the end user to use these parameters so I have the the parameter set to hidden.

When I move from Design to Preview for the report, I get a blank screen with the text 'The Security' parameter is missing a value'.  I've tried all the options that I can think of in the parameter properties.  The only way I can preview the report is setting the parameter to visible although that defeats the purpose.

Any ideas or am I barking up the complete wrong tree with this?

I've tried selecting different properties for the parameter although nothing seems to work as i'm envisioning. Changing the parameter to visible let's me view the report but I do not want the end user to have control over this parameter.

The objective is for, depending on the report, the developer can select the parameter so in the footer of the report, it reads: This report is for the intended audience of ___ and is @Security. So the developer selects the appropriate security level and that value of the parameter is listed in the report footer.

Comment: When you show the parameter, does it bydefault contain some value? or you fill in Value manually. Probably you need to set for your parameter "Allow Null Value". Could you post screenshot for your Parameter.

Comment: I figured out part of it (I needed to specify a default value) - although now my question is  -  What if I want to pass two values from the parameter to display on the report?  I have the parameter set to Hidden, and to Allow Multiple Values.  The available values (4) are one's that I specified.  However, there is no way for me to select more than one since the parameter is hidden and I get #error when previewing.  So how can I pass multiple values for a single parameter into the report if the parameter is hidden?